# How can I see the rate of my wireless card?

Tags: command-line, wifi, monitoring, command

I am setting manually the bit-rate of my wireless card !

> sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M

Where can I see if it is applied, because the command does not give any feedback !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo iwconfig wlan0`. That will list all of the current parameters.

```
auser@acomputer:~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"a.ssid"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:01:02:03:04:05   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:114   Missed beacon:0
```